# IE10 CSS Animations

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations

I have read that animations are supported in IE10, however mine don't seem to work.

I have tested in IE11 and other browsers, seems to work fine.

My code:

```
div {
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
    background-color: $white;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-name: line; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: line;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes line {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    100% {left:0px; top:0px; height: 85px;}
}

@keyframes line {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    100% {left:0px; top:0px; height: 85px;}
}
```

[Live URL](http://staging.whitstabledesign.com/M4C/) - it's the timeline section. You should see lines being drawn between each box.

Comment: Incorrect, @repzero; IE has never required prefixing of the `animation` properties.

Comment: I take this back you are right

Comment: for me, using document mode emulated - F12 - it worked just fine for IE10